# issue php connect with mongodb on nginx server which is hosted on ubuntu

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx

I tried to connect PHP with MongoDB. I have installed PHP, MongoDB, and MongoDB extension on Ubuntu, but I can't see mongo extension in PHP configuration.

Comment: And what is your question? Are you sure that you have enabled the MongoDB extension?

Comment: yes, I have added the extension

Comment: And what do you mean by "I can't see mongo extension in PHP configuration"? How did you add the extension?

Comment: sudo pecl install mongodb as well as add extension in php.ini extension=mongodb.so, but when I echo phpinfo then I cant see mongodb extension

Comment: And that's all? How did you enable the extension after installing?

Comment: adding the extension=mongodb.so in php.ini

Comment: Are you sure that you edited the proper php.ini? Several might exist

Comment: I think yes, but I saw more than one php.ini are available but I have edited phi.ini which is present in the path of loaded php.ini of configuration file

Comment: did you reboot your webserver?